# Symbol alignment with looseness

Tags: tikz-pgf, alignment

I'm trying to create numerals using Tikz. I am happy with the look of the numerals, though the 9 doesn't align with the others. I suspect it is the "looseness" component of its code, but am not 100% sure. Is there another way to define the 9 so it looks like the one below but aligns horizontally with the 7 and 8? Thank you.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\Seven}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [white] (0,-0.5) -- (0,0.5) -- (0.6,0.5);
\draw[ultra thick, line cap=round] (0.0,0.4) -- (0.5,0.4) -- (0.2,-0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand{\Eight}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [white] (0,-0.5) -- (0,0.5) -- (0.6,0.5);
\draw[ultra thick] (0.25,0.4) arc(90:-90:0.2cm and 0.2cm);
  \draw[ultra thick] (0.25,0.4) arc(90:270:0.2cm and 0.2cm);
   \draw[ultra thick] (0.25,0) arc(90:-90:0.25cm and 0.25cm);
  \draw[ultra thick] (0.25,0) arc(90:270:0.25cm and 0.25cm);
\end{tikzpicture}}


\newcommand{\NineA}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [white] (0,-0.5) -- (0,0.5) -- (0.6,0.5);
% \draw[ultra thick, line cap=round] (0.2,0.15) circle[x radius=0.25,y radius=0.25]; 
    \draw[ultra thick, line cap=round] (0.45,-0.5) -- coordinate[pos=0.5](-mid)(0.45,0.4);
    \draw[ultra thick, line cap=round]   (0.45,0.4) to[out=170,in=260,looseness=25]   (0.45,0.3);   
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \Seven\\
\Eight \\
\NineA  
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct, A possible remedy is to use `bbox` tikz library. It provide in such a case tight bounding box around Bezier curves:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{bbox}   % <---

\newcommand{\Seven}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [white] (0,-0.5) -- (0,0.5) -- (0.6,0.5);
\draw[ultra thick, line cap=round] (0.0,0.4) -- (0.5,0.4) -- (0.2,-0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand{\Eight}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [white] (0,-0.5) -- (0,0.5) -- (0.6,0.5);
\draw[ultra thick] (0.25,0.4) arc(90:-90:0.2cm and 0.2cm);
  \draw[ultra thick] (0.25,0.4) arc(90:270:0.2cm and 0.2cm);
   \draw[ultra thick] (0.25,0) arc(90:-90:0.25cm and 0.25cm);
  \draw[ultra thick] (0.25,0) arc(90:270:0.25cm and 0.25cm);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand{\NineA}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[bezier bounding box]    % <---
\draw [white] (0,-0.5) -- (0,0.5) -- (0.6,0.5);
% \draw[ultra thick, line cap=round] (0.2,0.15) circle[x radius=0.25,y radius=0.25];
    \draw[ultra thick, line cap=round] (0.45,-0.5) -- coordinate[pos=0.5](-mid)(0.45,0.4);
    \draw[ultra thick, line cap=round]   (0.45,0.4) to[out=170,in=260,looseness=25]   (0.45,0.3);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\Seven\\
\Eight \\
\NineA
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful, thank you!